# Custom Display Template - Apply predefined filter on initial search results load

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search-results, display-template

We have customised display templates and there are custom refiners as well which is all working fine, instead of refined value change, we have added **Apply filter** button and results filtered on this button click event.

What recent requirement we have got it, one of the custom filters should be default applied when search results initially load.

Can someone please help how to achieve this? It is a checkbox filter and if I keep it checked state on load and apply a filter on the checked event, this filter never cleared.